# ios6 Tweet via SLRequest and edit the source field

Tags: twitter, ios6

I'm trying to edit the "source" field of a tweet that's documented: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/tweets

The below code successfully posts a tweet, however when I pull up that tweet on tweetdeck it still says it's being posted via ios.  It feels like NSDictionary isn't the place to be editing this, however it doesn't seem like there's a better place in the flow and I can't find any examples/documentation to clear it up.  Thanks for any help in advance.

```
NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": contents,
                          @"source": @"<a href=\"http://www.example.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">App Name</a>"};            
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL
                                 URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                                    requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                    URL:requestURL parameters:message];

postRequest.account = twitterAccount;
[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
                 NSLog(@"Twitter HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse 
                                                      statusCode]);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you're referring to explains the meaning of returned fields.

You cannot set the source by yourself, there's no API for that.

You can find the `POST statuses/update` API [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update).

Additionally, the code you posted uses API version 1 which was shut-down a while ago.

Now you have to use API version 1.1.